# Matlab detect rectangle from image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm trying to create Matlab function that checks if there is an rectangular box in image. Rectangle might not be straight and that's why I'm trying to create function that checks if there is rectangle form and later I'm going to use function to rotate image so that the rectangle is straight.

Currently I'm trying draw lines around the box but the problem is that the lines are too short (they dont surround the whole box). Also I need some tips that would help with this problem. I should somehow check if there is rectangular box in the image.

```
I=imread(img);
I=rgb2gray(I);

BW = edge(I, 'prewitt');
figure, imshow(BW);

[H,T,R] = hough(BW);

P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold', ceil(0.3*max(H(:))))
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P)

figure, imshow(I), hold on

for k = 1:4
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2]
   plot(xy(:,1), xy(:,2), 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color','red');
end
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample image

Comment: Does the image only consist of this box?  It's hard to provide you with any insight if we don't see an example.

Comment: I added the link to image

Comment: Have a look into edge detection

Comment: This has already been solved.  See the duplicate link.  What you can do first is detect the dominant orientation by calculating an edge detection and detecting the most prominent lines from this edge image by the Hough transform.  You'd then determine the angle of the most prominent lines and create an inverse rotation to orient it so that it's straight.  Once you're there, you can use your logic to figure out if there's a rectangle in the image.  Good luck!

Comment: BTW, don't use the Prewitt detector.  Please use Canny.  It's the best one that's out there in terms of automated edge detection algorithms.